# flutter The window for obtaining location authorization under ios has always been displayed in English, and has been internationalized

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

this demo also has the same problem: https://github.com/cander0815/flutter_demo

ios multi-language, when obtaining permissions, only prompts in English are displayed, no prompts in other languages are displayed

flutter msg:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/cander/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (6 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2
```

version: geolocator: ^5.3.0

InfoPlist.strings(English):

```
"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "In order to give you a better user experience, I needs to use your location, including: Get the location added by the device when you add the device";
```

InfoPlist.strings(Chinese, Simplified):

```
"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "为了给您一个更好的用户体验, 我需要使用您的位置, 包括: 您添加设备时获取到设备添加的位置";
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete question? If so, please add it into your post and consider revising your question title to make it shorter and clearer. At the moment the title is not a question either. It makes it difficult to decipher what exactly it is you would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by Localizations in Info.list